# How to upload wallet secret key to aws kms

Tags: security, blockchain, amazon-kms, secret-key, wallet

Hi I'm junior backend developer.

I have to safety management company's wallet secret key. So I'm trying kms.

But, I was blocked at step 4: Import the key material

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QukLB.png)

I think encrypt step 3 is wrong or my secret key file format is wrong. I encrypted secret key using this code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rncq.png)

I wonder

1. if it is possible to manage the wallet secret key with AWS kms.
2. is the problem that the secret key is not a symmetric key?
3. Is there something wrong with my encrypt step?

I have to finish this today. Could you help me?

I also tried encrypting with openssl. But i also couldn't solve this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/und8B.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Instead, copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

KMS is used for managing key-pairs for encryption/decryption purposes.  Keys can be symmetric if both sides need to be able to decrypt and encrypt information, or asymmetric where only one side needs to encrypt/decrypt (like when AWS encrypts your data before storing it on S3 and decrypts it before returning it to you).  Wallet cryptography is almost always asymmetric

KMS is not meant as a repository for wallet secrets.  If your AWS credentials are compromised, then so is your wallet.  Developers often have more access rights than they should have, potentially leaving your wallet vulnerable to anyone in your organisation with an AWS access key and secret.

If you want to keep a key secret safe, export it to a USB drive, or print it out on a piece of paper and put it in a safe!